# WhatsApp Clone in android for message identifier

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, whatsapp

I'm working on a chat app message like whatsapp clone in android using firebase.

Right now the application can chat user to user.

My problem right now is the messages was no identifier that the other user see the messages of one another.

In order to make a solution I concat the userId and currentUserId so that it will be the unique message identifier since I'm using firebase-auth.

So my question right now is if this solution is somewhat ok? or any suggestions for message identifier for app chat?

This is some of my code in my ChatActivity for retrieving chat messages

```
mFirebaseDatabaseRef!!.child("messages").child(mFirebaseUser!!.uid+userId))
```

Here is saving the messages for every message I push both for user devices

```
mFirebaseDatabaseRef!!.child("messages")
    .child(mCurrentUserId+userId)
    .push()
    .setValue(friendlyMessage)

mFirebaseDatabaseRef!!.child("messages")
    .child(userId+mCurrentUserId)
    .push()
    .setValue(friendlyMessage)
```

Here is the sample generated format in firebase (It will both generate two unique coming from two userId's want to chat)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So my question right now is if this solution is somewhat ok?

Yes it is. Since this solution works and help you get your job done, it ia a very good solution. You may wonder, is there a better one?

There is no better or perfect solution for how to identify the messages in your app. The best solution, is the solution that fits your needs and makes your job easier. And I personally don't think that can be a better solution than the one that you are comfortable with.

> or any suggestions for message identifier for app chat?

Since it is a one to one chat application, the way you identify a "chat room" that contain messages it right, since it is very easy to query. You can simply attach a listener on `fromUidtoUid` or `toUidfromUid` reference, and that's it, you got all the messages of a conversation between two users.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?